# Sending sigaction / sigqueue through shell

Tags: shell, signals

I have a c++ program that handles several signals to perform different actions, using signal:

```
    signal(SIGHUP, signal_handler);
```

I wanted to extend this signal handling to allow me to send different action requests to my program, and found that using sigaction I would be able to receive extra information along with the signal:

```
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, 0);
```

For what I could find, I am able to send this type of signals from other programs, setting extra information on the sigval object, so that I know, on the receiving end, what the program was requested to do.

What I wanted to know is how can I send this type of signal information through a shell script on bash. Is it possible? I can send signals to my program using `kill -S SIGHUP [PID]` but I do not find a way to send that extra parameter using `kill`, so I was wondering if bash has any command that emulates the sigaction / sigqueue behaviour, allowing me to send signals to my app without having to develop another application to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information seems to be outdated. From my `sigaction` man page:

> **Undocumented.**
>         Before the introduction of SA_SIGINFO it was also possible to get  some
>         additional  information, namely by using a sa_handler with second argu-
>         ment of type struct sigcontext. **This use is obsolete now.**

Comment: I did not know that... Is there another way of achieving this, that you know of?

Comment: Most programs will use, say, 3 different signals to request 3 different actions, but to pass more information, typically the info is put in a known file, then the program is signalled and it reads the file to see what it should do. If there is a lot of communication going on, programs will instead do something like open a (unix domain) socket and listen for requests on it. If you want to easily communicate from bash, you could have your program read a named pipe (see `mkfifo`), as bash can easily write to such a device.

Answer (score 2):

This works. First, set `SA_SIGINFO` to `.sa_flags` to signal an interest in extra info:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void act(int s, siginfo_t *i, void *v)
{
    //printing from here is unsafe but this is for testing 
    //purposes only
    printf("pid=%d val=%d\n", i->si_pid, i->si_value.sival_int);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction sa = { 
        .sa_sigaction=act ,
        .sa_flags = SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
    } ;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    printf("%d\n", (int)getpid());
    for(;;){
        pause();
    }

}
```

Second, create your own kill(er) app capable of sending such extra info:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    union sigval val = { .sival_int = atoi(argv[2]) };
    sigqueue((pid_t)atoi(argv[1]), SIGUSR1, val);
}
```

You can try compiling these two and you should be able to use the second executable to send integers to the first one  (`./second  pid int`).

The manpages should provide you with more information on how to build on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send and receive extra parameters using `sigqueue()` and `si_value` in `siginfo_t`. "This use is obsolete now" in `sigaction()` is perhaps referring to use of `sa_handler` with two arguments with second one being `sigcontext`. After introduction of `SA_SIGINFO`, there's no need to use such an undocumented handler, since all handlers take `siginfo_t` argument which has the `si_value` field.

However, I don't know a way to queue a signal with payload from the shell, you may need to write a small C program for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with newer version of kill from procps-ng:

```
kill -q <value> -<signal> <pid>
```

See: https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/merge_requests/32